# Vertex AI Managed Notebook, get subnet/IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

How can I find IP for vertex AI managed notebook instance? The service is differing from user managed notebooks in certain sense. The creation of an instance doesn't create a compute instance, so it's all managed by itself.

My purpose is to whitelist the set of IPs in Mongo atlas. Set of IPs being of all the notebooks in that region. I'm using google-managed networks in this case.

I've a few doubts here:

- Since within managed nb, I can change CPU consumption, will this reinstantiate a new cluster, with entirely new IP, or it will be 1 from among a group of IPs?
- Is it possible to add a custom init script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to a database service on GCP, create a network (or use the default) and instantiate the notebook using this network (`Advanced options`) and create the white list for this entire network . It's required because the managed notebook creates a peering network on the network you will use, you can check you in `VPC Network` ➞ `VPC Network Peering`.

[image]

If you want an external IP, it will not work. Google managed notebooks **does not use external ips**, they basically access the internet via NAT gateways (does not matter if you use google or own managed networks) so you will not be able to do what you want. Move for user managed notebooks (where you can assign a fixed external ip) or white list any IP on your Mongo db service if you are not in a production environment.

About yous doubts:

> Since within managed nb, I can change CPU consumption, will this instantiate a new cluster, with entirely new IP, or it will be 1 from among a group of IPs

For the internal network it may change when you restart or recreate the notebook instance. For an external network, it does not exists and explained.

> Is it possible to add a custom init script?

Basically not. But you can provide custom docker images for the notebook.